# hide div when mouse hasn't moused over x time, vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

asked a similar question earlier but i've been stuck at this for a while.

i have a div that v-shows on certain events, for example when hovering over `div1` and clicking on `div2`. i want to make so this div disappears when the mouse hasn't touched it for a certain amount of time, let's say three seconds.

my problems are that i cant use v-on:mouseleave (because the div appears without the mouse being on it) so i'd need something that after a certain delay toggles v-show on the div. is there something i'm missing? what should i be using?

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to use a component and add an event listener in the mounted hook that uses a timeout to set a flag attached to `v-show`, so:

```
Vue.component('my-deiv', {
  template: `<template id="block"><div v-show="show">A div</div></template>`,
  mounted(){
    this.$el.addEventListener('mousemove', () => {
      setTimeout( () => {
        this.show = false;
      }, 3000)
    })
  },
  data(){
    return{
      show: true
    }
  }
});
```

Now whenever the mouse moves over the div it fires the timeout, here's the JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nb80sn52/

**EDIT**

If you want to hide the `div` when the mouse has not moved on it for a certain amount of time - but not when the mouse exits, then you can restart the timeout each time the mouse moves and then cancel it altogether when the mouse leaves, here's the updated version:

```
Vue.component('block', {
  template: "#block",
  mounted() {
    this.timer = null;

    this.$el.addEventListener('mousemove', () => {
      clearTimeout(this.timer);
      this.timer = setTimeout(() => {
        this.show = false;
      }, 3000)
    })

    this.$el.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
      clearTimeout(this.timer);
    })
  },
  data() {
    return {
      show: true
    }
  }
})
```

And the JSFiddle for that: https://jsfiddle.net/utaaatjj/

Comment: awesome! this is something i'll be using, thanks man.

although, this one hides the div when the mouse has moved over it. is there any way to instead check if the div has been moused over for a certain amount of time, using setTimeout?

Comment: thanks man. because it's a school assignment i didn't change my whole structure up, because i have to make it fit the specifications. i'm starting to make it work, simply by using v-on:mouseover and v-on:mouseleave functions but i'm currently having problems with clearTimeout().

so, my timeout is stored in `timer`. so, for example when i mouse over, i'm trying to do `v-on:mouseover="clearTimeout(timer)"` but it doesn't seem to be working. this.timer doesn't work either, it simply doesn't want to clear it. what am i missing?

Comment: also -- i want to store my setTimeout in `timer` but it doesnt seem to work when putting it in data, where i have the rest of my global variables? i'm trying to make it a global variable but it doesn't seem to like that... i could store it locally in every method but i think that might be the root of my issue with `clearTimeout`!

Answer (score 0):

You could `setTimeout` in your component render function (or any other function) which would change `this.visible = true` to `this.visible = false` after a predefined period of time.

Comment: ah, that's what i'll be looking to use, thanks!
 i wonder though, is it possible to check if the mouse hasn't hovered over the div? i know i can check mouseleave etc but i need to be able to see that the div in question hasn't been hovered over for a certain amount of time.

Comment: @akre_11 you can store the timeout in a variable and reset / cancel the timeout on mouse enter.

Comment: thanks man! that's what i've done now but i'm having problems using clearTimeout();. on mouseover i'm trying to do `v-on:mouseover="clearTimeout(this.timer)`, where `timer` is the var i've stored my timeout in but it doesn't seem to want to clear it. what am i missing?